# Running Selenium Webdriver with a proxy in Python not changing IP

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I am trying to make a proxy in python using selenium i have a list of free proxies from https://free-proxy-list.net/ but the ip i get is always the same, there is something wrong with this setup?

```
PROXY = proxy_list[11]
options = Options()
options.headless = False

webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy":PROXY,
    "ftpProxy":PROXY,
    "sslProxy":PROXY,
    "noProxy":None,
    "proxyType":"MANUAL",
    "class":"org.openqa.selenium.Proxy",
    "autodetect":False
}
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r'geckodriver.exe')
# Set the interceptor on the driver
driver.request_interceptor = interceptor 
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

EDIT: i am running according to the response the following code:

```
url = 'https://www.whatismyip.com/es/'
PROXY = proxy_list[6]
options = Options()
options.headless = False

firefox_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
firefox_capabilities['proxy'] = {
    'proxyType': "MANUAL",
    'httpProxy': PROXY,
    'ftpProxy': PROXY,
    'sslProxy': PROXY
}
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r'geckodriver.exe', capabilities = firefox_capabilities)
# Set the interceptor on the driver
driver.request_interceptor = interceptor 
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(50)
driver.quit()
```

But the ip in the webpage is always the same, dunno if missunderstood the use of the proxy or i am doing something wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Firefox browser,

```
...
# set proxy
firefox_capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
firefox_capabilities['proxy'] = {
    'proxyType': "MANUAL",
    'httpProxy': PROXY,
    'ftpProxy': PROXY,
    'sslProxy': PROXY
}
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r'geckodriver.exe', capabilities = firefox_capabilities)
```

If you use Chrome,

```
...
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=' + PROXY)
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: what is the code for chrome?